# How to get a straight Nurbs

Tags: bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I have added a nurbs curve. Im extruding it in the L direction and i do not need that curve shape. On the red axis its going straight but when i turn to green axis it makes a curve. With the orange line highlighted i want that my nurb also be in that shape and not in the curve. In the curve tab @ resolution preview i have deceased to 1 yet to i cant find that shape. After have that L shape nurb curve i have bevel object with the plane. Any solution[image]

Comment: If you want to achieve sharp corners, Nurbs curves are not the best choice, at least supported in Blender. Try Path or Bezier set to Vector handle from V menu.

Answer (score 2):

Does this setting work for you?
[image]

Comment: Not completely satisfied it look doing manually. As Mr Zak said i tried using vector and solve the 75% . I have taken a plane and converted to curve and i have taken a small plane converted to curve. with the big plane i have curve to object with small plane and it did not made the rectangular but the edges are cut (like a photo frame)

Comment: Can you please add some text explaining the process. Gifs can be great, but should not be the only thing in the answer.